# How to navigate the Special Characters window with the keyboard?

Tags: macos, internationalization

Is it possible to use the special characters window only with the keyboard?

i.e., I know in `textedit` for example you can activat the special characters window with Alt+Cmd+T. But:

- How do you bring focus to this window with the keyboard?
- How do you perform a search only with the keyboard?
- How do you select a symbol from the list using the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Language and Text pane in System Preferences. Under Input Sources, check the sources you want to use, and check "Show input menu in menubar."

This will put a flag or similar symbol in your menubar. Populate the Character Viewer by choosing Customize List from the gear menu at upper left. Add to Favorites by dragging to that title.

Copy and paste a selection doesn't seem to work in Mountain Lion, but you want keyboard anyway--and dragging from page or Font Variation works just fine.

Comment: You explain how to customize Character Viewer, but the question is about using the keyboard to navigate it.  For example, after ⌃⌘Space to activate it, I can't find a way to dismiss it again from the keyboard, nor can I find a way to focus the search field inside Character Viewer.