# How to interact with dialog boxes using keyboard that appear not to allow keyboard interaction?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I recently asked a question: [How to navigate the Special Characters window with the keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71638/how-to-navigate-the-special-characters-window-with-the-keyboard)

However, it seems to me that OSX has a class of dialog boxes that seem to be inaccessible to keyboard activation.

- Finder - View Options
- TextEdit - Fonts
- TextEdit - Special Characters
- OmniFocus - Inspector

I.e., there will be a shortcut key to show the dialog box, but in order to interact with the dialog box you need to use the mouse or trackpad. I.e., Control + backtick does not activate them. I note that this is not the case with all such dialog boxes. E.g., most preference dialog boxes, the info dialog box in Finder, etc. permit keyboard activation.

- Does this class of dialog boxes have a special name?
- What do people who prefer to use the keyboard almost exclusively do with such dialog boxes?

Comment: I can’t remember what they are called, but I do know that they never take keyboard focus and thus have a light grey title bar.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little bit of searching and found this page on [OSX accessibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXKeyboardShortcuts/OSXAXKeyboardShortcuts.html).

They might be called "Utility Windows".

- Control + F6 Moves focus to the first (or next) utility window
- Control + Shift + F6 Moves focus to the first (or  previous) utility window

Once inside, Tab and Shift tab can be used to navigate.

Interestingly, these shortcut keys worked with the following dialog boxes

- Finder - View Options
- TextEdit - Fonts

But did not work with these

- TextEdit - Special Characters
- OmniFocus - Inspector