# Can't navigate dialog using keyboard only

Tags: keyboard, finder, settings, mojave, accessibility

I checked [this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71645/how-to-interact-with-dialog-boxes-using-keyboard-that-appear-not-to-allow-keyboa/71654#71654) and I have a problem navigating through dialog boxes that is not answered there.

I'm copying + pasting folders and when the dialog "Stop/Replace/Merge" appears I can't navigate with the <kbd>TAB</kbd> because the dialog box never gets focus.

If I click on the dialog box then I can tab between the buttons, but that defeats the point of using the keyboard and slows me down (I have several folders to paste in different locations).

Is this a bug? I do have "Full Keyboard Access" turned on. I also checked [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38015/how-can-i-switch-dialog-buttons-using-the-keyboard) and nothing there helps me. I already updated to Mojave.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It’s annoying, macOS is generally pretty good with keyboard shortcuts but there are one or two places where it doesn’t work!

I think the dialog *does* have focus (it’s technically a window and appears ticked in the Window menu, and you can press ⌘M to minimise it) but it just doesn’t allow you to use the keyboard to activate the buttons. Let’s both send feedback to Apple on this.